# SSDT SQL script generation bug

Tags: sql, sql-server-data-tools

I have an issue with generating scripts from a MSSQL Database using Visual Studio 2017 with SQL Server Data Tool. The issue is that I have a lot of errors when generating the scripts. The generated script looks something like this:

```
SELECT
        GO.ID_GUID
        ,GO.NAME
        ,GO.CODE
    ,SO.CURRENCY_CODE
FROM 
    GENERIC_OWNER GO
INNER JOIN
    SALES_OWNER SO
    ON GO.ID_GUID = SO.GENERIC_OWNER_ID
WHERE
    GO.BLOCKED <> 'Y'
```

So apparenty GENERIC_OWNER get the name GO which is a keyword and from there I get a lot of errors. Is there a way to get around this issue? The script are going to be used to automate database migration so I need the tool to generate scripts without displaying syntax hightlight errors and without errors in the error log.

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Even if go is key word, your script should work fine, please edit your post and add error you are getting.

Comment: "GO" is only a keyword for SSMS, not for SqlServer itself. Are you getting those errors while *running* this command?

Comment: @PawelCz Hi, Yes the script does work, however having these errors would obscure real errors and that would make the migration more difficult. I don't know if there is a way to supress the errors and make sure that any real errors get's detected.

Comment: Updated question to clarify that the main problem here is that it is reporting errors on a functioning script due to how it was generated.

Comment: Try [enabling `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33538543/11683) in the project settings?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because GO is a keyword for your client tool, say ssms, it is possible to change batch delimiter, but instead you can just add square brackets around the keywords like so:

```
SELECT
        [GO].ID_GUID
        ,[GO].NAME
        ,[GO].CODE
    ,SO.CURRENCY_CODE
FROM 
    GENERIC_OWNER [GO]
INNER JOIN
    SALES_OWNER SO
    ON [GO].ID_GUID = SO.GENERIC_OWNER_ID
WHERE
    [GO].BLOCKED <> 'Y'
```

better yet don't use GO as an alias :)